# How can I separate my XML record using XSLT script?

Tags: xml, xslt, separator

I have a scenario in which I have to separate data by the same IDs.

Here in the example, we have different records of items and we have to separate them by id in one root element.
Input payload:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <items>
        <item>
            <Id>101</Id>
            <Name>Anand</Name>
            <Des>Udaipur</Des>
            <Qty>5</Qty>
            <Amount>100</Amount>
        </item>
        <item>
            <Id>102</Id>
            <Name>Kartik</Name>
            <Des>Haryana</Des>
            <Qty>18</Qty>
            <Amount>199</Amount>
        </item>
        <item>
            <Id>101</Id>
            <Name>xyz</Name>
            <Des>ds</Des>
            <Qty>6</Qty>
            <Amount>90</Amount>
        </item>
        <item>
            <Id>101</Id>
            <Name>xyz</Name>
            <Des>ds</Des>
            <Qty>9</Qty>
            <Amount>120</Amount>
        </item>
    </items>
</root>
```

Output payload:

```
<root>
    <items>
        <item>
            <Id>101</Id>
            <Name>xyz</Name>
            <Des>ds</Des>
            <Qty>5</Qty>
            <Amount>100</Amount>
        </item>
        <item>
            <Id>101</Id>
            <Name>xyz</Name>
            <Des>ds</Des>
            <Qty>6</Qty>
            <Amount>90</Amount>
        </item>
        <item>
            <Id>101</Id>
            <Name>xyz</Name>
            <Des>ds</Des>
            <Qty>9</Qty>
            <Amount>120</Amount>
        </item>
    </items>
    <items>
        <item>
            <Id>102</Id>
            <Name>dd</Name>
            <Des>dd</Des>
            <Qty>18</Qty>
            <Amount>199</Amount>
        </item>
    </items>
</root>
```

Can anyone help me with that by XSLT script or by using the groovy script? Above is the XML code of the list item and we have to separate them by ids.

Comment: It is usually called grouping, see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info or any XSLT tutorial for an introduction, then give it a try.

Comment: There are lots of questions and answers about grouping in XSLT and I'm going to choose one of them (rather arbitrarily) as a duplicate. Search for XSLT grouping and you'll find plenty of others. Do remember: grouping is much, much easier in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks for reaching out. We already tried the grouping, I'm unable to solve this using grouping. If you have anything similar example or anything useful related to this then please help me.

Comment: Any of the `group-by` examples in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info should help.